# is it possible to have System.NullReferenceException in this line?

Tags: c#, .net

We caught an exception (don't know why there is no line number in that Win7 Embedded system):

```
Exception Message: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

in this line, I think:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(HandleSaveStatus, (EvDoSaveStatus)systemSwEvent);
```

The only place I can think about is `(EvDoSaveStatus)systemSwEvent`. But I did similar test as the following:

```
            SystemSwEvent ev = new EvDoSaveStatus();
            ev = null;
            EvDoSaveStatus evt = (EvDoSaveStatus)ev;
            string str = "Is it good?";
```

There is no exception thrown. That means `(EvDoSaveStatus)systemSwEvent` will be fine even `systemSwEvent` is `null` somehow.

If one of the members of the `EvDoSaveStatus` became null, it should not casue exception in above `ThreadPool` statement. Am I right?

**EDIT:**
in this case:

```
    case "EvDoSaveStatus":
    {
 Log.logItem(LogType.DebugDevelopment, "EvDoSaveStatus", "dsm::publish()", "EvDoSaveStatus received");
 ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(HandleSaveStatus, (EvDoSaveStatus)systemSwEvent);
  break;
   }
```

And we have that log entry available.

**EDIT2:**
the entire publish method:

```
public void publish(SystemSwEvent systemSwEvent)
{
    try
    {
        switch (systemSwEvent.eventName)
        {
            case "EvLogin":
                {
                break;
                }
            case "EvLogoff":
                {
                break;
                }
            case "...":
                break;
            case "EvDoSaveStatus":
                {
                    Log.logItem(LogType.DebugDevelopment, "EvDoSaveStatus", "dsm::publish()", "EvDoSaveStatus received");
                    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(HandleSaveStatus, (EvDoSaveStatus)systemSwEvent);
                    break;
                }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.logItem(LogType.Error, "Exception in publish()", "dsm::publish()", "Exception:" + ex + "\nStackTrace:" + ex.StackTrace + "\n" + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you absolutely sure it is this line that is the culprit?

Comment: @Lasse: not 100% but 99% sure

Comment: @jfs: this is all we have: Exception:System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at XXX.XXX.DSMgr.dsm.publish(SystemSwEvent systemSwEvent) StackTrace: at XXX.XXX.DSMgr.dsm.publish(SystemSwEvent systemSwEvent) Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Why don't you provide the whole code for dsm::publish?

Comment: @jfs: please check again, updated

Comment: Can you provide the body of HandleSaveStatus?

Comment: Why don't you have the line number of the stack trace of the exception?

Comment: It's possible, you got one.  There's nothing there that would let guess that it crashed at that location.  The systemSwEvent object being null would be more likely.  Deploy the .pdbs to get a line number.

Comment: yes, pdb is in place now. test is in progress, it will take few hours to finish

Answer (score 2):

```
ev = null;
EvDoSaveStatus evt = (EvDoSaveStatus)ev;
```

will result in `evt` being null. You can pass null as the second parameter of `QueueUserWorkItem`, but the callback you're queuing needs to handle it.

`HandleSaveStatus` must be a [WaitCallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.waitcallback.aspx), so it takes an object parameter. What does it try to do with that object? Does it handle the case where it is null?

```
public void HandleSaveStatus(object state){
    if (state == null)
    {
        return; // or whatever else you want to do with a null state
    }
    // Do work with non-null state
}
```

Comment: if happened in HandleSaveStatus method, the exception should be thrown from there which is a different location.

Comment: The OP says "I think" it is at the QueueUserWorkItem line. However, you can pass null as a parameter on that line, so unless ThreadPool is null, the "think" is wrong. The work item gets queued and errors when it executes. Let's see the body of HandleSaveStatus and see if the parameter is used without checking for null.

Comment: Sorry, you are the OP. I'm not feeling my best today. Anyway, you say "I think," but without a stack track, it would be best to confirm.  Paste the following into a new WinForms app, build, and run it (not in debug). You'll get a similar crash report. private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(HandleSaveStatus, null);
        }

        public void HandleSaveStatus(object state)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(state.ToString());
        }

Answer (score 2):

Wild guesses here...

According to the [documentation for QueueUserWorkItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4yd16hza.aspx), it will throw a NullReferenceException only when the first parameter, `callback`, is null.

Is HandleSaveStatus actually a method?  If it is an instance method, are you sure you're not calling this code from a base class constructor before the object is initialized?

Try splitting apart the line to this and seeing whether the error is still on the second line:

```
WaitCallback callback = new WaitCallback(HandleSaveStatus);  
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(callback, (EvDoSaveStatus)systemSwEvent);
```

The explicit constructor call (`new WaitCallback`) is actually more verbose than necessary, but it shows that the delegate creation is another possible source of NullReferenceExceptions.

Comment: In this case, HandleSaveStatus must be a method or the code wouldn't even compile. The case where you'd have a null callback would be if you're assigning it at runtime and the compiler can't do this early detection. Paste the following into a Form and try to build, you'll get The name 'HandleSaveStatus' does not exist in the current context private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(HandleSaveStatus, null);
        }

        public void HandleSaveStatus2(object state)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(state.ToString());
        }

Comment: Voting this up anyway because it could definitely help someone in the future who is doing that kind of thing.

Comment: @druttka -- Yes, the code in my answer requires that `HandleSaveStatus` be a method, not a delegate variable.  It would be nice to know for sure which one he has.